# javascript escape newlines in string

Tags: javascript, html

I have to define a variable in a template so my template renderer will replace values in it. I then have to use this variable in some javascript functions I have.

The variable is itself some html and I want to be able to format it so that it looks like HTML and not an unreadable super long one line string...

```
<script>
var myHTML = "
  <div>
    content
  </div>"
</script>
```

The only way I can see to get it to work would be to do this (really ugly)

```
<script>
var myHTML = ""
  +"<div>"
    +"content"
  +"</div>"
</script>
```

Is there a friendly way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for javascript string literals and I wasn't coming up with anything

Comment: why not to put the whole template in a single file "template.html", then you can use an ajax httrequest to put the whole content inside a variable? This could make the whole thing much readable and easy to update.

Answer (score 2):

Any new line characters inserted in the source are part of the template literal. Using normal strings, you would have to use the following syntax in order to get [multi-line strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var myHTML = '<div>\n    content\n</div>';

console.log(myHTML);
```

For a more advanced usage case you can implement your solution on top of one of these [top 5 JavaScript templating engines](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396):

- [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [Underscore Templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template)
- [Embedded JS Templates](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)
- [HandlebarsJS](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [Jade templating](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used and friendly approach to this is to put the template string in its own `<script>` element with the type attribute set to `text/x-something`, as this element will be accessible by javascript, but not shown by the browser.

This allows you to write HTML (as well as template markup) as you normally would, without the need for escaping or special handling of newlines.

A working demo of this approach:

```js
//get the template string
var myHTML = document.getElementById("template1").innerHTML;

//check that myHTML contains the template string
console.log(myHTML);
```

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="template1">
  <div>
    content
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You just have to put backward slash "\" at the end of the each line (except last line) of the string and then press enter to go in newline.
2. In your case:

   ```
   <script> 
    var myHTML = '\
         <div>\
           content\
         </div>\
        ';
   </script>
   ```